# Can I ping between two computers using the same router on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

It's as the title states. I do not have two pcs at the moment to test this myself, but I'm curious if I could use one pc to ping the other, and vice versa, if they were both connected to the same router?

Comment: Some additional reading that would probably be beneficial:  [Ping to Windows 10 not working if “file and printer sharing” is turned off?](https://superuser.com/q/1137912/650163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should just work<sup>tm</sup>, assuming that:

1. Both PCs are on the same network, or
   both PCs are on their own network and a router has been properly setup to route between these.
2. Neither has a firewall configured to block pings (more formal ICMP echo request).
3. You use a regular router and not some multi device commonly called a router but with much more functionality including build in firewall software.
   The last got added because some devices are a combination of wireless accesspoint, switch, router, DHCP server, DNS server, **firewall** etc. And some of those do isolate devices on the same **wireless** network from eachother by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Maybe I'm missing something, but is there any reason you suspect it to not work?

As long as the computers are both on the same netmask, you'll be able to ping them. If they're both pointed to the router and are using that box as the default gateway you'll be fine. Pretty much the only way it won't work is if you mess up manual configurations for the IPs and/or gateways/subnet (ie go out of your way to not use the automatic configurations)

Comment: I'm presently taking a class and a classmate of mine told me a switch had to be used. See I thought it would work but I don't have the means of actually testing it.

Comment: No switch is needed. Just a connection and a switch is the easiest/simplest form of connecting. But a direct wire between the two interface will also work. And what commonly is called a 'router' also has a build in switch. I guess the classmate over simplified the answer.