# Unable to ping in windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, cisco-router

I do IT at the home office for a national Senior living facility. We have a facility that has been somewhat neglected network wise. 
there is a cisco 1900 asa there, and a cable modem to the isp. 
I was not able to ping with a hostname on the Cisco. I resolved that issue, it will not ping IP and hostname.

now to my problem. 
None of the win 10 pro machines on the inside of the network, using DHCP, can ping out. I can put a url into chrome and reach the site. So it can at least partially resolve dns.

I have tried adding 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to the computer's dns in the network setting, instead of using DHCP for DNS, and nothing, no ability to ping.

Any ideas?

Could it be port related on the firewall on the Cisco?
Anything I can check on the windows side?

baffled.

Comment: So the ping just times out?

Comment: yeah, 100% packet loss. super weird.

Comment: Might be blocked in the W10  software firewall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this....https://superuser.com/questions/1137912/ping-to-windows-10-not-working-if-file-and-printer-sharing-is-turned-off

Comment: no, thats checked